# Zip a folder and files to the folder

Tags: excel, vba, zip

I have zipped a folder and contents through excel vba.eg: I have a folder named 2178 and 2 pictures in it.

1. `2178_photo.jpg`
2. `2178_poa.jpg`

After zipping I required 3 files in the zipped folder.

1. `Folder Name`
2. `2178_photo.jpg`
3. `2178_poa.jpg`

But in the current program I am getting only 2 files:

1. `2178_photo.jpg`
2. `2178_poa.jpg`

---

```
Sub NewZip(sPath) 'Create empty Zip File
    If Len(Dir(sPath)) > 0 Then Kill sPath
    Open sPath For Output As #1
    Print #1, Chr$(80) & Chr$(75) & Chr$(5) & Chr$(6) & String(18, 0)
    Close #1 
End Sub

Sub Zip_All_Files_in_Folder()
    Dim FileNameZip, FolderName
    Dim strDate As String, DefPath As String
    Dim oApp As Object DefPath = "D:\KYC\"
    FolderName = "d:\kyc\2178"     ' the zipping folder name '<< Change
    strDate = Format(Now, " dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")
    FileNameZip = "d:\kyc\2178.zip" ' to be zipped folder'DefPath & Range("A" & i).Value & ".zip"
    'Create empty Zip File
    NewZip (FileNameZip)
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    'Copy the files to the compressed folder
    oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(FolderName).items
    'Keep script waiting until Compressing is done
    On Error Resume Next
    Do Until oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).items.count = _
       oApp.Namespace(FolderName).items.count
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Loop
    On Error GoTo 0
    MsgBox "ok " 
End Sub
```

Please help , I required 3 names in the zip file.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LU-KfOzlobg4B6zATrSzKRgIHky8YVG_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I am getting codes for select a folder and zip all the files. my requirement is select a folder and zip that folder (including its contents). Thanks

Comment: What does this 3rd file need to be? Just a text file with the name? Or do you need the files you're zipping to be 'inside' a folder with the same name in the zip file?

Comment: yes. Mike Exactly what you have written. Zipping files to be inside a folder with the same name. Thanks